# WebLogic staging mode affects runtime performance?

Tags: weblogic

As a general question, are there any reasons that setting the Staging Mode to "nostage" instead of "stage" could cause performance hits? I was originally using "stage" mode, but after some issues with redeployments, I decided to try "nostage". This caused the application to perform almost two times slower. After switching the staging mode back to "stage" in the console, the slowdown was gone.

I was under the impression that the staging mode only "determines how deployment files are made available to target servers" (from the Oracle documentation page), and would not affect the runtime. Is this normal behaviour? I'm having trouble finding information on any links between staging mode and runtime performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stage or nostage should not impact runtime performance. It is hard for me to find out what might cause your performance slowdown without further information, but one thing I can suggest is to switch back to staging mode if that seems to give you the better performance before you figure out the root cause. As to the redeployment issue you mentioned in your answer, you did not provide any details, but I guess it might be related to WLS still picking up the old files instead of new files. You can do some extra steps during your deployment to fix that

1. Undeploy your app
2. Shutdown the whole domain
3. Delete the tmp/stage/cache directories under each managed servers
4. Start the servers in the domains
5. Do a new deployment.

Of course, it sounds cumbersome, but you can automate all these into your deployment scripts.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Are you aware of any particular setups in which the staging mode could affect the runtime? I'm having a hard time finding more information on the issue because, like you mention, it doesn't seem like staging mode should have any affect on runtime. About the deployment issues, most of them have to do with applications not undeploying correctly. It is very inconsistent and they can sometimes end up timing out. I found nostage to be more reliable in this sense.

Comment: No. I agree with you that staging mode should not affect runtime performance. If you have a undeployment issue, here is something you can try. At one project, we store the config.xml in the version control system like CVS. Thus whenever there is any change, we know who did what and when. The config.xml has everything except the app-deployment entry. During deployment, we shut donw the domain, overwrite the config.xml with the one from CVS and then start the servers. Since the app-deployment entry is missing, the WLS is started without the application, thus there is no undeployment needed.

Comment: Will the solution you mentioned work for redeployments? I was under the impression that in stage mode, the server stores the artifacts in its own directories. I'm assuming that removing the config.xml entry does not actually delete the server's copies of the artifacts. During a redeploy, will it overwrite the application? Thanks for the suggestion, it's something I will consider doing.

Comment: Before you start the servers, you need to delete tmp/stage/ cache folders in each of the server directory.